# Where is System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel in .NET Standard 1.6?

Tags: c#, .net

Where is Parrallel in asp.net core 1?

```
Parallel.ForEach(results, (x) =>
    {
        foo();
    });
```

The name 'Parallel' does not exist in the current context .NETStandard,Version=v1.6

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll need a reference to `System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel`

You can use nuget to get this.
Alternatively, add the following to your `project.json`

```
  "dependencies": {
    //
    "System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel": "4.0.1"
  },
```

**Note:**
This is now out of date, since there's no more `project.json`

As per comment, add this to your csproj:

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel" Version="4.3.0" />
```

Comment: In Newer Version, Add below in .csproj file -

          <PackageReference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel" Version="4.3.0" />

Answer (score -3):

Parallel is not available in .Net Standard 1.6